# Copulas - what marginals can I use? (theory)

Tags: distributions, econometrics, fitting, copula, marginal-distribution

For my research I am using various copulas and I fit different marginal distributions to my data. I've studied the topic of inter-variable dependency quite a bit, however, I do not recall the limitations of fitting *exotic* marginals (some non-Gaussian distributions for example, or even common ones).

**My question:** Can I literally use any marginal distribution that is transformable to a uniform distribution for my copula? **Note:** I do not need to recover the marginals after transforming. E.g. Casella and Berger and Leemis show many dependencies of distributions and how to transform the RV's to get there which is nice since I can always find my ["path"](https://fsalamri.files.wordpress.com/2015/02/casella_berger_statistical_inference1.pdf) (p. 627). However, ease of implementation is important too. From this image it seems to me that choosing a student t-distribution is not that "handy" as I need to perform various transformations? Even though the student-t copula is often used for my application.

Comment: The whole point of using copulas is the ability to select arbitrary marginals.

Comment: All marginal distributions are univariate.  Perhaps you meant to write "uniform"?  But that is part of the definition of a copula, so one wonders what you are trying to ask.

Comment: Ah I see, yes I indeed meant uniform and not univariate. @whuber